# Как убрать хлебные крошки с главной страницы (Yoast SEO)

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

Не могу убрать хлебные крошки с главной страницы, помогите кто может, пробовал и display: none, но везде удалялось и через код php с ис домом, не помогает ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать данный фильтр, например, в файле functions.php используемой темы:

```
function custom_wpseo_breadcrumb_output( $output ) {
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) return false;
    
    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_output', 'custom_wpseo_breadcrumb_output' );
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, ЭТО ПОМОГЛО! Но, есть минус, на главной странице теперь div с крошкой, который был когда там, просто скрыт и в html он есть и из-за этого боюсь верстка полетит, если начну паддинги и прочее двигать, дабы контент натянуть на место где крошки были, но вот вопрос! Можно как-то убрать из html на главной крошку эту?

Comment: Значит при выводе хлебных крошек вы их дополнительно обернули в данный контейнер.

Comment: Слегка не понял, что мне нужно сделать

Comment: @iFlyZed если не поняли, что вам выше ответили, то скорее все вам проще будет для этого элемента добавить display:none; а лучше найти в коле этот элемент и выполнить проверку является ли эта страница главной или нет